# How to set style in the database

Tags: qgis, layers, style, mysql, qgis-2

Is it possible to set style layers in the database? (QGIS) [MySQL database]

I would like to set and share my style with other users, so when they open the layer it's still as my style.

Answer (score 4):

From QGIS 2 advanced [changelog](http://changelog.linfiniti.com/version/1/) you can read :

> Feature: Save styles in your database
>
> If you are using a database vector data store, you can now store the layer style definitions directly in the database. This makes it easy to share styled layers in an enterprise or multi-user environment.
> (source : http://changelog.linfiniti.com/version/1/)

It works for sure with pgsql. I'm not sure it works with MySQL.

An associated screenshot ([fullsize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyICU.png)) is there :
[image]

Comment: Umm... I'm not sure that MySQL is work too.Thanks :)

Comment: And switching to pg is not an option?

Comment: I don't know much about database.
sorry...